# Happen before relationship in Java Memory Model

Tags: java, java-memory-model

I have a question about Java Memory Model.

In the following scenario:
initial: `a = 0; b = 0;`

```
T1:
    a = 1;
    l.lock();
    b = 1;
    l.unlock();

T2:
    l.lock();
    read b;
    l.unlock();
    read a;
```

Can I say if the value of `b` read by `T2` is `1`, then the value of `a` read by `T2` must be `1`?

To my understanding, the `unlock` in `T1` flushes both the value of `a` and `b` to main memory, and the `lock` in `T2` makes sure both `read a` and `read b` can get the latest value.

Am I right?

Edit: I just specified that they are locked on the same lock.

Comment: What are you locking on?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, doesn't matter. In Java the code would look like `a = 1; synchronized (o) { b = 1; }` and `synchronized (o) { x = b; } y = a;` for some shared object `o`.

Comment: @aioobe If they were `synchronized` on different objects, would the behavior be the same?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. Read my answer, and consider what could happen if the two synchronized blocks could execute simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I say if the value of b read by T2 is 1, then the value of a read by T2 must be 1?

Yes. It's guaranteed. An operation can move *into* a synchronized block, but not *out* from it. See Jeremy Mansons blog post [Roach Motels and The Java Memory Model](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.se/2007/05/roach-motels-and-java-memory-model.html).

This means that, while `read a` can move up before `unlock`, (and up above `read b` due to instruction reordering) it can never move up above the `lock` instruction of `T2`.

Same reasoning applies for `a = 1`: It can move down into the synchronized block (and below `b = 1` due to instruction reordering) but not passed the `unlock` instruction.

However, if we swap the instructions like that, they are both covered by the lock, which means that if `T2` reads a `1` from `b`, then `T1` will already have written a `1` to `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I find some useful information from http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html.

In the What does synchronization do? section, it says:

'Synchronization ensures that memory writes by a thread **before** or during a synchronized block are made visible in a predictable manner to other threads which synchronize on the same monitor. After we exit a synchronized block, we release the monitor, which has the effect of flushing the cache to main memory, so that writes made by this thread can be visible to other threads. Before we can enter a synchronized block, we acquire the monitor, which has the effect of invalidating the local processor cache so that variables will be reloaded from main memory. We will then be able to see all of the writes made visible by the previous release.'

'This means that any memory operations which were visible to a thread before exiting a synchronized block are visible to any thread after it enters a synchronized block protected by the same monitor, since all the memory operations happen before the release, and the release happens before the acquire.'